# Python cant get output from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, python, sccm

Im trying to use this code to get a list of Actions in the SCCM pushed into python, but all I get in retun is an empty bytes string.

```
count = r"""
if (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator"))
{
  $arguments = "& '" +$myinvocation.mycommand.definition + "'"
  Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList $arguments
  Break
}

$CMGR = New-Object -ComObject CPApplet.CPAppletMgr

$ClientActions = Out-String ($CMGR.GetClientActions() | Select Name).count
$ClientActions
"""

def runPS(command):
    import subprocess
    process=subprocess.run(["powershell", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass", command],stdout=subprocess.PIPE);
    print(process.stdout)
```

All this outputs is `b''`

What am I doing wrong???

EDIT: I figured part of it out. Its because it's tecnically running another powershell within this one (Python >> Powershell >> Admin Powershell), and the second one doesn't return its value to the first. (Python <> Powershell >> Admin Powershell)

Comment: Try simpler Powershell, such as a hello, world! example. Does its output work? If it does, something's wrong with the SCCM Powershell. If it doesn't there's something in acquiring output from process.

Comment: @vonPryz I did that, and it in fact does get a return value. The strange part is when I run this in a Powershell Window (no python) then it returs the correct number (in this case "9")

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `check_output()` instead of `run()` here. That allows you to detect a non-zero exit code from the child process. [More information here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output). The Powershell might be failing for some reason, but you're not capturing stderr or checking the return code.

Something like this might be more robust:

```
def runPS(command):
    import subprocess
    output = subprocess.check_output(["powershell", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass", command])
    return output
```

> EDIT: I figured part of it out. Its because it's tecnically running another powershell within this one (Python >> Powershell >> Admin Powershell), and the second one doesn't return its value to the first. (Python <> Powershell >> Admin Powershell)

Hmm. Sorry, I don't know powershell, so I can't help you with that half of it.